# jQuery DataTable - JSON in hidden field

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the popular DataTable jQuery library to render some tabular data in Coldfusion. I have the following jQuery...

```
var tbl = $('#tbl-people').dataTable({
   aaData : [<cfoutput query="qryPeople">
      [
         '#FName#',
         '#LName#',
         '<input type="hidden" value="{\"test_id\":123,\"test\":\"john\"}" />'
      ]<cfif currentRow NEQ recordCount>,</cfif></cfoutput>
   ],
   aoColumnDefs... and a few other pieces that I'm leaving out for the sake of brevity.
});
```

My question (and problem) revolve around the hidden field that is being created as the third column in the aaData. I would like to store the FName and LName as JSON in the value of the hidden field; however, to first test it I decided to just hardcode in some test JSON. My problem is that hidden input field is being mangled when it is finally rendered as HTML. The resulting HTML for the hidden input looks like this...

```
<input type="hidden" test_id":123,"test":"john"}"="" value="{">
```

It seems evident to me that at some point the double quotes in the JSON are being misinterpreted or misunderstood by something, hence the screwed up HTML. Also, please note that I stuck in the standard backslash in order to try to escape the double quotes in the JSON (but seemingly to no avail).

Comment: What is the need for the extra brackets `{` in the value?

Comment: and what would you like the output to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't monkey with sticking JSON in a hidden field; it's just tedious. I was able to easily get it into an HTML span tag, and then set the css display to 'none', effectively making it a hidden field.